# Filter have_posts()/ the_post()

Tags: filters

What is the best way to filter the posts being displayed?

For example in my functions.php file I want to have something like

```
add_filter( $tag, 'filter_posts');

function filter_posts(){

   if(is_home()){

   //return custom post query that will be used in loop
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you're going about this the wrong way.  Don't filter the posts in `functions.php`, instead, define custom loops and [include them when needed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part).

In a simplified example, let's say your theme only has `header.php`, `footer.php`, `sidebar.php`, and `index.php` for the structural files.  Your `index.php` would look something like:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
        <div id="main">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Pretty simple.  You have a header, a sidebar, and a footer in external files and the main page content defined in the main file.

But you can add some logic here and, rather than include a generic loop each time, you can have a custom loop for everything.  So instead, your `index.php` would look like:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">
    <?php
    if( is_home() ) {
        get_template_part( 'loop', 'home' );
    } else if ( is_single() ) {
        get_template_part( 'loop', 'single' );
    } else {
        get_template_part( 'loop' );
    }
    ?>
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then you define your custom loops in `loop-home.php`, `loop-single.php`, and `loop.php`.  These custom loop pages can define any custom query you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

see custom queries in the codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries

the category exclusion is a particularly good example